# Execute one instruction on CPU

Tags: assembly, cpu

I wonder, is there non-emulator way to ask CPU to process single instruction?
I mean using actual CPU like somewhat an interpreter.

Comment: Yes. You can either just execute it and jump back to your code, or have it in a different process that you single step using debugger features of your OS and architecture.

Comment: Do you have a specific instruction set architecture in mind? x86 processors for example have the trap flag for single stepping.

Comment: @fuz yeah, you right. I think about x86 primarily

Comment: @nonForgivingJesus Then check out the trap flag.  Basically, setting it generates an interrupt after every instruction executed, so you can execute a program one instruction at a time.  Mainframes with the S390 architecture even have an `EX` (execute) instruction to execute arbitrary single instructions.

Comment: In the old days you could set a switch on the front panel for single step. Some times there were two: single step machine cycle, or single step machine instruction.  But nowadays that is handled by breakpoints and software in cooperation with special hardware meant to assist debugging.  Otherwise the CPUs are designed to execute as many instructions in bulk as they can.